# Error: Can't open display:

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, putty

[image]

I am working my way through 'The linux command line' (http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) . Since I don't have a local linux environment and I have to work in windows , I am telnetting into an Ubuntu 14.4 LTS instance on EC2 , with putty. On page 114 , when I run the xlogo command I get:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-22-65:~$ xlogo
Error: Can't open display:
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: You should run a X server on Windows and forward X connection via SSH.

Comment: Questions like this belong on unix.stackexchange.com or superuser.com. It's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xlogo will try to access the current Xserver to display a logo.  If you're telneting to a box, you will not have an X server available, which is what that "can't open display" message is saying.  It's trying to look at your `DISPLAY` environment variable to use that to show the logo on, but you don't have a display to use, and thus have nothing in your DISPLAY variable.

You will need access to an X server somewhere to do that step.  One option would be to install cygwin on your Windows machine.  Then you wouldn't need the remote linux box for most steps I imagine, because you could just use your local cygwin environment.  Even if you want to use the remote box still, if you use cygwin and launch an xterm with it, you could `ssh -X <host>` and that will export your DISPLAY to that remote machine so it can display back on your windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for your help Eric, is there a way to do this without installing cygwin?

Comment: The problem is that you need an X server, and while there may be others available Windows, I'm not familiar.  If you can see the display of the VM you're accessing you could use that instead of SSH, like if you can see it in a browser or via VNC or something like that.  I'm not familiar with EC2 and what sort of access you get with it.  If you don't want to see it for real, you might be able to install a virtual frame buffer in the VM and use that as your display, but then you'll just have to trust that things are working without being able to see them for yourself.

Comment: I am having the exact same problem, but working on wmware Ubuntu 20.04 from a win 10 laptop.  It worked fine many times. I am also working thru the same book. The problem for me - and here I am guessing - started after I had to do some kill processes, quite a lot for removing a test user I should have logged out but persisted to show up in top. Maybe I killed too much?  The killing processes i part of the same chapter in the book.

Comment: @mortenlund I suspect one of the things you killed is the X server.  If so you'll have to restart that (how you do that will depend on your system of course).  If that's not straightforward you should probably ask a new question, but I think the [Super User](https://superuser.com/) site would be a better place for it than here.

Comment: @Eric Renouf  Yes it was something with x, can´t remember precise - but could it be something x-11 or so?

Comment: @EricRenouf  So you are saying that you actually do not have to restart Linux, but only restart X-server. I will look into that on super user. Thanks for advice, best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comment under Eric Renouf answer, I am working thru the same book. That part of the book have some testing of creating users, groups, shifting users, group permissions etc. I found that I needed to log the same user out quite some times. The last time logging that user out, I got a message saying xlogo is terminatet, like it was hanging on that user?
After everyone was logged out, I logged in as sudo and everything worked again.